# how to edit coredata value then save context to overwrite old values?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdictionary

I am trying to edit a item in one of my `coredata` tables/entities. I am not 100% sure how to do this but I think its along these lines.

First you create the context, then `fetchrequest` the entity using a predicate to select the exact item from the table/entity. then save these values into the correct var type update the values then some how overwrite the existing item with the new values.

The last part is where I am stuck, this is the code I currently have:

```
- (void)editSelectedInstall:(NSString *)invGuid {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];


    if (context == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Nil");
    }
    else {


        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Install" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"invGUID==%@",invGuid];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *myArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@", myDictionary);




// Here I will update the values & then save the context? 
// For example I think I am to update the items like this:

myDictionary.num = @"1234";
myDictionary.name = @"new name";
    }


}
```

I think I'm almost there I just need help saving the context so that it overwrites the previous values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//loop through result set and update as required
for (Install *temp in myArray) {
    temp.num = @"1234";
    temp.name = @"New name";
}

//save
[context save:&error];
```

Comment: Just I would strongly advice don't save inside for loop. Just move [context save] out of it, and place it after for loop.

Comment: still working on it wont be long then will see if it works.. i just have about 20 vars to edit ... lol

Comment: so I am doing exactly like you show me, however when I try to read the  install entites from core data i get this error "-[NSNull intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: yep, I have lots of install values, but my code is only calling one of them back, so that for loop you told me to write only actions once. when i save context am i just overwriting the one install and keeping the others that were excluding using the predicate the same or am i dumping everything?

Comment: debugged the crap out of it, and see im putting in a null value into one of the 16bit int... changing now

Comment: Because you use the predicate, only the "records" (not sure if I should call them records!) you pull back will be updated, the rest will be untouched

Comment: wel i have that method progressing right through now, however it dosnt seem to be saving properly, as when i reload my view which pulls the data from coredata it shows the old values.

Comment: After you save, run another fetch (as oppose to reloading the view) to see what the values are - to see if they saved or not at that stage

Comment: So it seems that it is there, however there are some very weird results also inserted into some of the outputted entities which is causing all the trouble....... Still working on it, I think i might know what the problem is ill answer your question as correct shortly as i tihnk its correct :)

Comment: boom got it to work.. totaly my fault, I hadnt put in the correct valueforkey. there are two values, one is oldkey other is newkey i was using the old key when it needed ot be the new one. whoops. thanks for the help